# Не читает html-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Есть на сайте построенного на Wordpress галерея NextGen и к ней подключено  Fancybox версии 2.1.7 (из оф.сайта).

Проблема следующая 
Когда в описание каждой картинки галереи закидываю html tag то он на сайте так и показывает

`<div class='descrip_img_gall'> <div class='title_descrip_img'>Tytuł: </div> </div>`

Я так понимаю что сам FancyBox весь текст который есть в описании галереи выводит как обыкновенны текст.

Как прописать чтоб читались html

Пробовал решение

`$('.codeIt').each(function(i){
  $(this).text($(this).html());
});`

Все равно результат неменяеться.

Буду рад даже советов в какую сторону "копать"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно преобразовать строку из HTML в DOM с помощью функции parseHTML():

```
$('.codeIt').each(function(i){
    var text = $(this).text(); // Возможно придется использовать $(this).html();
    var html = $.parseHTML(text);
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но в результате оказалось что сама галерея 2.1.7 имеет баги, по этому поменял на другую.